# In the Harvard referencing style, is it wrong to put references in footnotes?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I have a discussion with my mate about how to reference with the Harvard referencing style.

[image]

I would say it is wrong to do the referencing like in the picture below.

My suggestion was that the footnotes was to explantion of synonyms or something like that and all references should be in the end of the paper work, so the reader have all the references in one or two pages, so it's easier to get an overview of all references.

Am I totally wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome, what exactly is your question? `harvard` describes a whole series of author-year citation. Some fields use citations in footnotes. Advantage, not searching at the end of the paper, but at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks! 
My question is:
If you look at the picture, is it right to make references in the footer?

Comment: See the updated comment above. Yes, depending on the field.

Comment: Ahh ok. Im in the engineering field. 

But thanks!

Comment: Footnotes in engineering are uncommon. No matter what you do, if you have a clean database (bib file) and use `biblatex`, you will be fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to write an academic paper, rather than about academia itself. When writing a paper, you should consult the appropriate style guide for your field, or imitate other papers in your field. Questions such as "Should I use footnotes or endnotes" depend too much on your specific situation to have a general answer.

Comment: @OswaldVeblen I dunno, this sounds like "How do I use a certain format?" It'd be like "How do I cite a verbatim translation in APA?" Which I think would be on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is directly about Harvard referencing, I believe all Harvard referencing uses in-text citations. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthetical_referencing) supports this understanding.

Yes, you can use footnotes but they are used for clarification or comments, they are not used for referencing as the image in the question has done [therefore the author has cited improperly].

There are several sub-types of Harvard but ALL of them that I am familiar with are in-text, not based on footnotes (except as noted above).

Answer (score 1):

Footnotes are quite common in the humanities, and less so in science and engineering. Putting a reference in the footnotes *can* happen, according to the specific paper and citation style you are using. For example, the *Chicago Manual of Style* can use [either footnotes or parenthetical references](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html).